# Limit SQL query to only show results with more than one name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been stuck on this query for a bit and am wondering if anyone can point out where I am going wrong? The query is supposed to gather data for students who have taken more than one of three courses, shown as course codes. Ideally, this should only show results for those who have taken course FLA3304 + one or both of the other two. I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this problem.

This is my current attempt using SQL Server:

```
select name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
from StudentExams

where coursecode = 'FLA3304' and mark is not NULL
or coursecode = 'SST3771' and mark is not NULL
or coursecode = 'ELA3104' and mark is not NULL 

and name in (
    select name
    from StudentExams 
    group by name
    having count(name) > 1
)

group by name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
order by name
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice how your description is inconsistent. You first wrote "... have taken more than one of three" followed by "taken course FLA3304 + one or both ...". Those are very different goals. And be careful what you assume. Can a student take the same course multiple times? In other words, is <name, coursecode> unique in the table?

Comment: These are great considerations. I do agree that both of these goals were different. I was trying to achieve the "taken more than one of three" as a minimum goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your WHERE clause, will this work:

```
where coursecode IN ('SST3771', 'FLA3304', 'ELA3104') 
and mark is not NULL
and name in 
(
select name
from StudentExams 
WHERE name in (select name from StudentExams where coursecode = 'FLA3304')
group by name
having count(name) > 1
)
```

Comment: Not a problem. Please let me know if you require explanation of the code. I will add some comments, may be.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I read this like, select students with coursecodes SST3771, FLA3304, and ELA3104 that do not have null marks and only select students whose names include FLA3304 and occur more than once.

Comment: Set a = all students who sat for FLA3304, Set b = all students from set a who have >1 exams; result set c = all records for students with courses ( FLA3304 or SST3771 or ELA3104) and non-null mark and student name in set b.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HAVING clause where you set the conditions:

```
select name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
from StudentExams
where (coursecode = 'FLA3304' and mark is not NULL)
   or (coursecode = 'SST3771' and mark is not NULL)
   or (coursecode = 'ELA3104' and mark is not NULL) 
group by name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
having count(case when coursecode = 'FLA3304' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(distinct coursecode) > 1
order by name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want `exists` and no `group by`.  If you want more than one of the specified exams:

```
select name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
from StudentExams se
where se.coursecode in ('FLA3304',  'SST3771', 'ELA3104') and
      se.mark is not NULL and
      exists (select 1
              from StudentExams se2
              where se2.name = se.name and
                    se2.coursecode in ('FLA3304',  'SST3771', 'ELA3104') and
                    se2.mark is not null and
                    se2.coursecode <> se.coursecode
             );
```

If you specifically want `'FLA3304'`, then another `exists` is probably the simplest method:

```
select name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
from StudentExams se
where se.coursecode in ('FLA3304',  'SST3771', 'ELA3104') and
      se.mark is not NULL and
      exists (select 1
              from StudentExams se2
              where se2.name = se.name and
                    se2.coursecode in ('FLA3304') and
                    se2.mark is not null 
             ) and          
      exists (select 1
              from StudentExams se2
              where se2.name = se.name and
                    se2.coursecode in ('SST3771', 'ELA3104') and
                    se2.mark is not null 
             );
```

Comment: This is fantastic! The second query does exactly what I am needing. I didn't realize how out of practice I was with this. I appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: @PixelsOfMind . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept it.

Comment: It was close but there it was also showing results from students with only one course. I did have to modify it a bit and the answer below provided the exact results I was looking for. I did learn some great techniques that I never used before with your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking two different questions, and you need to analyze your problem to understand the data more.
Question #1: list of names who have taken any of the courses with a count greater than one.
  So, Is it possible for a person to take the same course twice?  If so, do you include that person?  The solution by Yogesh Sharma handles that case.
Question #2: list of names who have taken course FLA3304 and have taken another course.
That solution would look more like this:

```
   Select distinct(name)
     from studentExams
    where coursecode in ('SST3771', 'ELA3104')
      and mark is not NULL
      and name in
        (Select distinct(name)
           from studentExams
          where coursecode = 'FLA3304'
            and mark is not NULL
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this?

```
select name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
from StudentExams

where ((coursecode = 'FLA3304' and mark is not NULL)
or (coursecode = 'SST3771' and mark is not NULL)
or (coursecode = 'ELA3104' and mark is not NULL)) 

and name in (
    select name
    from StudentExams 
    group by name
    having count(name) > 1
)

group by name, coursecode, coursename, month, mark
order by name
```